# expression() is not changing in the plot

Tags: r, macos

I'm trying to write subscripts and superscripts in my ylab but is not working. I tried the code below but it appears exactly as it is in the code. I'm using the expression function. Any thoughts, I need help.

```
ggplot(gsw_mean_sd, aes(Day, average.ES, group=1))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  labs(title="Stomatal conductance",x="Time (days)")+
  ylab(expression(G[sw]~(mol~m^-2~s^-1)))+
  theme_bw()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGuqD.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error, the ylab is plotting as expected. And the light blue background in the image comes from what instructions?